# TypeError on fetch request on "e-raktakosha" web site API

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api

I am new to JavaScript. I was trying to make an API call.
My code:

```
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Basic dW5kZWZpbmVkOnVuZGVmaW5lZA==',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
  }
};
fetch(
  'https://www.eraktkosh.in/BLDAHIMS/bloodbank/nearbyBB.cnt?hmode=GETNEARBYSTOCKDETAILS&stateCode=21&districtCode=378&bloodGroup=all&bloodComponent=11&lang=0',
  options
)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

but I encountered with an error saying

> Error: Failed to fetch

1. This API call works perfectly with [Hoppscotch](https://hoppscotch.io)
2. If I try to hit the URL right on my URL bar, it also works fine.

Any help is strongly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around 'false' for body. Or just remove the line entirely.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: You can't have `body:` with a `GET` request.

Comment: @Barmar I tried what you said. But it gives another error saying `Error: Failed to fetch`

Answer (score 1):

As other People already mentioned, you can't pass a Body when doing a GET HTTP call, instead you can pass Query Params

Notice this part on the URL

```
hmode=GETNEARBYSTOCKDETAILS&stateCode=21&districtCode=378&bloodGroup=all&bloodComponent=11&lang=0
```

Still looking into the code it seems the server have a cors policy, look at this sandbox

See this codesandbox -> https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-mcclintock-exuzol?file=/src/index.js

Summary:

- GET accept body/payload but it could cause errors, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET
- Using the Web API (new headers, new request) for doing the HTTP call

[image: GET warning of body/payload usage]

> It is better to just avoid sending payloads in GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use body with a get request. The GET request is purely meant to collect back data from server, which allows you to sent Queries, not data on the request. Just remove `body:'false'` or use `body:false`. The best way is to remove the body from your request so unexpected input is not sent via this GET request.

Comment: I tried the same; but it did not work.